# Who was Joseph's steward?

Tags: yosef, miketz

When Joseph uses an interpreter in Genesis 42:23, some say the interpreter was his son Manasseh (Gen. Rabbah 91:8, Targum Jonathan, Targum Yerushalmi), but Torah doesn't say so.

The Torah doesn't give the name of Joseph's overseer either, but does anyone say  who the overseer of Joseph's house was?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Anae! Thanks for sharing the question.

Comment: The sort of exactitude that you reference regarding the word "na'ar" is characteristic of the approach called _parshanut_. The ubiquitous identification of anonymous characters with named characters, is typical of the approach called Midrash. They constitute two completely disparate exegetical approaches.

Comment: Is this two separate questions, who was Yosef's steward and what is a na'ar?

Comment: your question is awesome,  thanks.  But it's a bit  confusing if you modify questions after answers,  especially if you include the answers in the question afterward

Comment: Thank you for the insight mevaquesh, that's good to know.

Comment: I agree kouty. I was going to add the follow-up questions to the comments, but I misunderstood what the guide in the comment box meant by "adding new information". That's why I edited the post. I am new here so thanks for the tip to make posts better going forward.

Comment: If you have a followup question after receiving your answers here, please ask it separately as a new question post. I recommend our [tour] also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genesis 43, 16:

> And when Joseph saw Benjamin with them, he said to **the ruler of his house,** Bring these men home, and slaughter a beast, and make ready; for these men shall dine with me at noon.

Targum Yonatan:

> **לִמְנַשֶׁה** דִמְמַנָא אַפִּיטְרוֹפּוֹס עַל בֵּיתֵיהּ ‏
>
> to **Manasseh,** the overseer of the house.

**--> This was also Manasseh.**

Comment: @Rish my intent was to make the formula symmetrical to the words used concerning the first verse,  the OP said that Midrash and Targum said,  not that they did know,  sorry for grammar

Answer (score 1):

The Midrash Sekhel Tov (Genesis 43:16) states that this was Menashe:

> וירא יוסף אותם [אתם] את בנימין ויאמר לאשר על ביתו. זה מנשה